# Insert contents into Array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, logic

I have an empty array and I want to insert content in that.

This the code that I use:

```
document.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {

    var myArr = [];
    var newContent = myArr.push(e.keyCode);
    console.log(myArr);

});
```

When I press the keyboard, I want to store all keyCode pressed into one Array without deleting the existing values of that Array. Currently, it stores one value of the first press and when I press again, it replaces this value with a new one.

I want to have this form: ["value 1", "value 2", "value 3", ...], but what I get is ["value 1"]...["new value"] etc...

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Declare the array `myArr` outside the scope because each time when you do a `keypress`, **`myArr`** variable is getting initialized.

```
var myArr = [];
document.addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {
    var newContent = myArr.push(e.keyCode);
    console.log(myArr);

});
```

Check this [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/praveen_jegan/qc92v/1/)

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring your array i.e. var myArr. So every time it is creating new array.
So declare outside of current block.